# Input multiple dates into PySimpleGUI Multiline box

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multiline, pysimplegui

I would like to be able to paste a list of dates from Excel into a PySimpleGUI multiline box and save the entry as a pandas DateTime list.

This is my current code:

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Please fill out the following fields:", font=font)],
    [
        sg.Text("Date List", size=size, font=font),
        sg.Multiline(size=(20, 10), font=font, key="date_list"),
    ],
    [
        sg.Submit(font=font),
        sg.Button("Clear", font=font),
        sg.Exit(font=font),
    ],
]
window = sg.Window("Date list entry form", layout)
```

This is what I copy from Excel:

[image]

This is the output:

> ('Submit', {'date_list': '3/18/2020\n3/19/2021\n3/18/2022'})

How do I convert date_list to a pandas DateTime list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call method `str.splitlines` to `values['date_list']`, and iterate items by method `pd.Timestamp`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Courier New', 11)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Please fill out the following fields:", font=font)],
    [
        sg.Text("Date List", font=font),
        sg.Multiline(size=(20, 10), font=font, key="date_list"),
    ],
    [
        sg.Submit(font=font),
        sg.Button("Clear", font=font),
        sg.Exit(font=font),
    ],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        lst = values['date_list'].strip().splitlines()
        try:
            print(list(map(pd.Timestamp, lst)))
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong datetime format')

window.close()
```

```py
[Timestamp('2020-03-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-03-18 00:00:00')]
```